# How to: RegEx in PhpStorm's Find & Replace

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I have this batch process where I need to refactor svg path's.
Because I have many occurrences in my project and I'm a lazy guy, I prefer to solve this task with find and replace as Regular Expression.

What I have:

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/_ui/desktop/common/images/svg/icons.svg#icon-arrow--white"></use>
```

What I want in the end:

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-arrow--white"></use>
```

My regex looks like this:

```
xlink="(.*)#
```

and its valid for my string on http://regex-testdrive.com/en/dotest and other sites.

How come, that if I use this expression in PhpStorm that it is not valid. 
If someone of you guys could provide me a hint, why I get 0 occurrences in PhpStorm with my RegEx, I'd be glad.

Comment: The regex is valid but it doesn't match your string because the string reads `xlink:href="...`

Comment: Search for: `xlink:href="(.*)#`; replace by: `xlink:href="#`; using `Regex` option checked -- does what yu need (based on your code sample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
xlink:href="[^"]*"
```

And replace the occurences with `xlink:href="#icon-arrow--white"`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vR3dR3/1).

Comment: thanks for this. i think i had made another mistake. this is: iam used, that PHPStorm previews the occurance of a string-search. But in the case of RegEx there are no previews. By just hitting "find" in the dialog, all ~1.3k where listed bottom. Just in case someone else has the same problem and is wondering, where the preview is.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the field where you input your search string (in your case your regex), there's a box to enable regex in search:

[image]

Simply check `Regex`, the regex is working then.

Comment: I have already done this setting, with the described resutl in the question.